# "Who'd have" vs "who would've."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The band Rancid has a song called "Who Would've Thought." However, [who would've thought](http://Who%20would%27ve%20thought) has less Google Book results than [who'd have thought](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=67f&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01idXl_kuuE6g6euhyPSCBY1nSaSg%3A1606399678534&ei=vra_X8_9H_TUmAW9m7a4CA&q=%22Who%27d%20have%20thought%20%22&oq=%22Who%27d%20have%20thought%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...53251.54242.0.54385.9.7.0.0.0.0.73.394.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.gZvBEumuz7w).

Example sentences:

> **He would've/he'd have** cooperated if we had offered him more money.
>
> **Who** **would've/who'd have** thought she'd have to study even after
> finishing university?

Are both common? Is one of them more "standard" than the other?

Comment: They are interchangeable. Neither is preferred.

Comment: As an American I feel like "who'd have thought" is considered somewhat more formal here. And Rancid is a punk band so they are likely to prefer the less formal usage (but also, just pick the version that scans better in a particular song). [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+would%27ve+thought%2Cwho%27d+have+thought&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) shows "who'd have thought" as more common in both English and American usage, particularly before ~1960; but of course that only reflects print sources, not everyday speech.

Comment: What @ThePhoton said (but I'm a Brit; there's no US/UK usage split here). In practice, I think it's just that the "preferred" form in writing was *always* the one reducing ***would*** to ***'d***, but [*We **would've** often used the alternative in **speech***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27d+have%2CWe+would%27ve&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20%27d%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWe%20would%20%27ve%3B%2Cc0). It's just that there's been a massive increase in the amount of more *informal* published texts in recent decades.